# How to embed a Xslt file in a C# assembly?

Tags: c#, xslt

I would like to embed a Xslt file in an assembly so that I can load the Xslt without having to read it from disk, and so that everything I need is contained within the exe.

i did this Xslt; [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61A4l.png)

**C#**

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); 
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TimeSoft.Entities.Properties.Resources.general.Xslt");
StreamReader s = new StreamReader(stream);
```

I don't want to read the file. So I guess these codes are wrong.
What i want is just get the file path how can i do that?

Comment: Does your code fail? Or what is "I don´t want to read the file. So I guess these codes are wrong" supposed to tell us?

Comment: it's not working right now and I really don't know what to do

Comment: Do you get an error? Which one, for which statement?

Comment: You are on the right lines here, but in my experience, getting `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream` to work correctly can be very fiddly; I'm afraid it's an area where I had a lot of trial and error in the .csproj file before finding something that worked, and I don't really know a magic formula for getting it right.

Comment: System.IO.FileNotFoundException @MartinHonnen

Answer (score 0):

I have tried a test with a .NET framework 4.8 console app and an embedded file named `sheet1.xsl` in the project/assembly named `XsltResourceNETFrameworkTest1` is found fine with `using (var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("XsltResourceNETFrameworkTest1.sheet1.xsl"))`. So this seems to work, you just need to get the assembly name and file name right.